# How to modify the elements in a list within list

Tags: python, list

I am very new to Python, trying to learn the basics. Have a doubt about the list.

Have a list:

```
L = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[3,4,6]]
```

The output should be:

```
[[2,4,6],[8,10,12],[6,8,12]]
```

The code that works for me is the following

```
for x in range(len(L)):
    for y in range(len(L[x])):
        L[x][y] = L[x][y] + L[x][y]
print L
```

It gives the output `[[2,4,6],[8,10,12],[6,8,12]]`.

Now I want the same output with a different code:

```
for x in L:
    a = L.index(x)
    for y in L[a]:
        b = L[a].index(y)
        L[a][b] = L[a][b] + L[a][b]
print L
```

With the above code the output obtained is:

```
[[4,2,6],[8,10,12],[12,8,6]]
```

I tried to debug about the above output. 
I put a print statement above the line `"L[a][b] = L[a][b] + L[a][b]"` for printing a and b. I was surprised to see the values of a and b are :

```
0,0
0,0
0,2
1,0
1,1
1,2
2,0
2,1
2,0
```

Again if I comment out the line `"L[a][b] = L[a][b] + L[a][b]"` then the values of a and b are as expected:

```
0,0
0,1
0,2
1,0
1,1
1,2
2,0
2,1
2,2
```

I suspect this might be happening due to the scope of variable in python and tried to study few stuffs about scoping in python. But I didn't get appropriate answer neither for scoping or the above question.

Comment: The answer is quite evident in the second loop of the inner `for` loop, once your you modify `L[0][0]` to `2` and then search for index of  `2`, but your code seems unnecessarily complicated, which begs me to ask.. Are you trying to achieve something simpler than your original code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other people have explained, when you use the `index` function, it finds the first occurrence of the value you are search for.  So the first time through you're loop (for the first row), it looks like

```
b = 1
[1,2,3].find(1)  # returns index 0
#Then you modify the first element of the list
b = 2
[2,2,3].find(2) #returns index 0 again!
```

For getting the indices in an easier, more deterministic way, you can use the `enumerate` function on a list.  It will provided you with an iterator that returns the index **AND** value as you move throughout a list.

```
for rowInd, x in enumerate(L):
    for colInd, y in enumerate(x):
        L[rowInd][colInd] = y + y
```

Note that this will do it in place, as in your original solution.

L = [[2, 4, 6], [8, 10, 12], [6, 8, 12]]

Comment: Thanks for the way of solving this.

Comment: Sure.  Make sure to select an answer when you get a chance.

Answer (score 1):

You modifying your list with statement - `L[a][b] = L[a][b] + L[a][b]`
e.g. -

```
L = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [3, 4, 6]]
```

`L[0][0]  = 1` initially 
Then you modify it as L[0][0] = 2

```
L = [[2, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [3, 4, 6]]
```

In next loop you search index for 2, which is 0,0 now, Because you modified list L.
I tried to print L along with a,b in your example. Result explains the behavior -

```
0 0
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [3, 4, 6]]
0 0
[[2, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [3, 4, 6]]
0 2
[[4, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [3, 4, 6]]
1 0
[[4, 2, 6], [4, 5, 6], [3, 4, 6]]
1 1
[[4, 2, 6], [8, 5, 6], [3, 4, 6]]
1 2
[[4, 2, 6], [8, 10, 6], [3, 4, 6]]
2 0
[[4, 2, 6], [8, 10, 12], [3, 4, 6]]
2 1
[[4, 2, 6], [8, 10, 12], [6, 4, 6]]
2 0
[[4, 2, 6], [8, 10, 12], [6, 8, 6]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the explaination

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieved your desired output is to use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). You could do as follows:

```
L = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [3,4,6]]
answer = [[2*el for el in sublist] for sublist in L]
print(answer)
```

**Output**

```
[[2, 4, 6], [8, 10, 12], [6, 8, 12]]
```

This iterates over each `sublist` in your list `L` and multiplies each `el` in the `sublist` by 2, thus achieving the desired result.

Comment: He has a working solution.  The question was why the second solution did *not* work.

Comment: also, note that this makes a copy of the list and op's original attempt was to do it in place.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following piece of code might be better
for x in L:  #iterating over the orig list
  for y in x: #iterating over the inner list
    [x][y] = [x][y] + [x][y]

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using your second method, then you need to store the results in a temporary variable:

```
L = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [3, 4, 6]]
M = [[0 for y in range(3)] for x in range(3)]
for x in L:
    a = L.index(x)
    for y in L[a]:
        b = L[a].index(y)
        M[a][b] = L[a][b] + L[a][b]
L = M
print L
```

Output:

```
[[2, 4, 6], [8, 10, 12], [6, 8, 12]]
```